# App\Entity\Site object not found by the @ParamConverter annotation

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to create a new tempate in my project in symfony to put a climbing converter. But it doesn't work. I have the error:

```
App\Entity\Site object not found by the @ParamConverter annotation
```

I put the function in the entity "site" as following :

```
/**
 * @Route("/site")
 */
class SiteController extends AbstractController
{
 
    public function upload( KernelInterface $kernel): Response
    {
 
       $imagesDir = $kernel->getProjectDir().'/public/uploads'; // équivalent à $this->getParameter('images_directory')
       dump($imagesDir) ;
        return $this->render('site/show.html.twig');
    }
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="site_index", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function index(SiteRepository $siteRepository): Response
    {
        
        return $this->render('site/index.html.twig', [
            'sites' => $siteRepository->findAll(),
              
        ]);
        
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/new", name="site_new", methods={"GET","POST"})
     */
    public function new(Request $request): Response
    {
        $site = new Site();
        $form = $this->createForm(SiteType::class, $site);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            //on recupère les medias transmises
            $media = $form->get('site')->getData();
            //on boucle sur les medias 
            foreach($media as $medi){
                //on génère un nouveau nom de fichier
                $fichier = md5(uniqid()) . '.' . $medi->guessExtension();
                //on copie le fichier dans le dossier img
                $medi->move(
                    $this->getParameter('images_directory'),
                    $fichier
                );
                //on stocke l'image dans la bdd
                $img = new Media();
                $img->setNom($fichier);
                $site->addMedium($img);

            }

            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($site);
            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('site_index');
        }

        return $this->render('site/new.html.twig', [
            'site' => $site,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/{id}", name="site_show", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function show(Site $site, MediaRepository $mediarepository, $id): Response
    {
        $media = $mediarepository->findBy(
            ['site'=>$id]
        );

        return $this->render('site/show.html.twig', [
            'site' => $site,
            'media' => $media,

        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="site_edit", methods={"GET","POST"})
     */
    public function edit(Request $request, Site $site): Response
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(SiteType::class, $site);//j'appelle le form
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            //on recupère les medias transmises
            $media = $form->get('site')->getData();
            //on boucle sur les medias 
            foreach($media as $medi){
                //on génère un nouveau nom de fichier
                $fichier = md5(uniqid()) . '.' . $medi->guessExtension();
                //on copie le fichier dans le dossier img
                $medi->move(
                    $this->getParameter('images_directory'),
                    $fichier
                );
                //on stocke l'image dans la bdd
                $img = new Media();
                $img->setNom($fichier);
                $site->addMedium($img);

            }
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('site_index');
        }

        return $this->render('site/edit.html.twig', [
            'site' => $site,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/{id}", name="site_delete", methods={"POST"})
     */
    public function delete(Request $request, Site $site): Response
    {
        if ($this->isCsrfTokenValid('delete'.$site->getId(), $request->request->get('_token'))) {
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->remove($site);
            $entityManager->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('site_index');
    }
    /**
     * @Route("/conv", name="site_converter")
     */
    public function converter():Response
    {
        return  $this->render('site/converter.html.twig');
    }

    
}
```

I checked others answers about this problem, but I still can't find out the solution. Do you have any ideas?
I put some more code so that it would be easier to understand. I hope this would be usefull. It's the route for converter that makes me problem. Thanks

Comment: You might have a route above that function maybe, like: `@Route("/site/{id}"` ?

Comment: I put som more code so that It will be more understandable

Comment: It's not clear when this error occurs. And you've got a lot of code that's commented out. Please remove it, it will make your question easier to read.

Comment: The code is not related. This error is trigger by some code that contains `@ ParamConverter`. If you do not provide the code, it's impossible for us to understand. I think your error is that the "Site" id you put in the URL does not exists considering the message is from here: https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/blob/676262b7a65a1033befbcf59e180d072df7504b6/src/Request/ParamConverter/DoctrineParamConverter.php#L103

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you have a route called `/conv`, you should declare it before declaring `/{id}` route, instead Symfony searches for a Site object with `id: conv` which is not found.

Move `converter` route and method declaration before your `show` route and method declaration.

Answer (score 0):

`{"code":404,"message":"App\\Entity\\ObjectEntityName object not found by the @ParamConverter annotation."}`

it's all about that object with that id haven't been found on your db.
if you get this error message with a `404 error code` it means that object with that id is not found from db.